# How to avoid hangup when clipping a large polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip

I am working with QGIS 2.12.3 Lyon. I have a shapefile which contains slope data for a large territory (layer - PenteSZ32). I want to lighten the weight of my shapefile by clipping it to a narrower surface that correspond to my study area. My study area correspond to a ripperian buffer of 1000 meters (layer - Donut_buffer_1000m).
[image: Clipping polygon 1]

In order to clip my polygon, i used the Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clipper as shown in the following image. This request worked previously with other layers. However, it doensn't work in this case. It bugs at 12 %. Both layer are in the same SCR.
[image: Clipping polygon 2]

Can you help me figure out what is the problem with my request ? Alternatively, do you have any other way to proceed you could suggest me ?

Comment: Do your layers have the same SRC (Right click > Properties > General tab)?

Comment: I belive that your question is too easy to find if you look for in google.

Comment: @Diogo Caribé i am familliar with the geoprocessing (at least the cliping). However, i was not able to suceed my operation, wich is why i am asking my question here.

Comment: I fail to see why this should be so heavily downvoted when the OP quite clearly states _"i was not able to **succesfully** clip my polygons"_. I've seen questions asking how to do basic operations which failed, and those questions were upvoted. @LaurentRobitaille-Lainesse - Perhaps you could upload the 2 shapefiles to a public server so that others could test it? Maybe this will remove some of the negative attention =)

Comment: According to your comments, i edited my post. I tried, with my approximate english, to be as precise as possible. If you wish any other information, i will be glad to upload it.

Comment: @LaurentRobitaille-Lainesse - From the screenshots, it looks like your "PenteSZ32" layer contains a lot of features. It could be that you just need to give QGIS more time to process the data. Even though it looks like it has crashed, QGIS is very stable and it's more likely that it is still processing. How long did you leave it for?

Comment: @Joshep - I left it for a few minutes. I will let it stand for an hour and keep the community in touch.

Comment: The layer « Pente SZ32» is 480 MO.

Comment: @LaurentRobitaille-Lainesse - That is a fairly large file size so my guess is that you just need to give it longer than a few minutes to complete =)

Comment: Have you tried without OTF enabled? And maybe check `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Check Geometry Validity` on both layers befor starting the clip. BTW Clipping to a bounding box rectangle might work faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few tries, i was able to suceed. You can compare the result before and after in the following images. Both image are at the same scale. I encountered a problem because of these two elements

1) My layer did not had the same SCR

2) I underestimated the amout of time for my computer to process the request

[image: Polygon 1][image: Polygon 2]

Here is a little reminder to succeed further operation of this kind

1) Make sure that all of your layers have the same projection (SCR)

2) Make sure you have selected the right layers in your Geoprocessing - Clipping operation

3) Avoid running any unnecessary programs while starting an heavy request

4) Give the software sufficient amount of time

Comment: I prefer to do such large tasks on the command line with GDAL ogr2ogr. QGIS does basically the same, but the GUI needs some RAM on its own. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151192/how-to-clip-a-big-shapefile-from-another-shapefiles-extent for some performance hints.

Answer (score 4):

In the menu bar go to Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clipper... . Then select as input layer the orange polygon and as clip layer the other one. This should generate a new territory layer which has the dimensions of the turquoise blue one you clipped against.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, i am not able to suceed this operation. The result is blank. I realize i was not clear on my question. I tried this way before.

Comment: Ok then. Did you already consider ArMoraer's objection? Maybe there's the problem.